# Why is GROUP BY necessary?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm learning, but aggregated was another keyword that came up. But why does it need to be grouped and what exactly gets grouped.

```
SELECT  
  usertype,
  concat(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) AS route,
  count (*) AS num_trips, --counting all trips (gives distinct value?)
  Round(AVG(Cast(tripduration AS int64)/60),2) AS duration --/60 to make into minutes not seconds and the 2 is for decimal place
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
GROUP BY 
  start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
Order by 
  num_trips desc
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the query does (conceptually - the actual implementation may vary)

- Get all rows from the table.
- Group them according to `start_station_name`, `end_station_name` and `usertype`. In other words, for every different combination of start station, end station, and user type, we have a separate group. For example, if there were 3 locations (`A`, `B` and `C`) and 2 user types (`1` and `2`), and assuming there were no trips from a location to itself, you would see groups like these:

  - LocationA, LocationB, UserType1
  - LocationB, LocationA, UserType1
  - LocationB, LocationC, UserType1
  - LocationC, LocationB, UserType1
  - LocationA, LocationB, UserType2
  - LocationB, LocationA, UserType2
  - LocationB, LocationC, UserType2
  - LocationC, LocationB, UserType2
- For each of these groups, calculate two values - `num_trips`, which is just the number of rows in the group, and `duration`, which is the rounded average of `tripduration/60` for all the rows in the group.
- Sort the groups (not the rows within the groups, but the groups themselves) by `num_trips`.
- Output only the first 10 of those groups (after sorting).